# Orthogonal projections over the space of linear functions.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

I've encountered the following exercise:

> In the space $C[0,2\pi]$ with internal product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} fg$, determine the trigonometric polynomial of $a+b\cos(x) + c\sin(x)$ which better aproximates the function $f(x) = x$.

I know this could be solved by calculating the orthonormal projection of the trigonometric polynomial over $f(x)$, but I don't know how that'd be calculated, as I can't see any basis (let alone any orthonormal basis for $f(x) = x$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You are suggested to pick the approximating function which is in the span of the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{1, \sin x, \cos x\}$ already.

In a different view of your question, you are asked to provide the projection of $f(x)=x$ onto the vector space $span(\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: Is that the same as projecting $a+b\cos(x)+c\sin(x)$ over $f(x) = x$?

Comment: @Rodrigo not at all, what you are suggesting would find the projection of some function onto $f(x)=x$. Instead you need to find the projection of $f(x)$ onto the span of $\mathcal{B}$..

Comment: I see. I thought about the problem incorrectly. 

Thanks for being amazing!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

You need to find an orthonormal basis $\{f_1, f_2, f_3\}$ for the subspace $\operatorname{span}\{1, \sin x, \cos x\}$ and then your desired function will be
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \langle f, f_i\rangle f_i$$

Check that we can take
$$\{f_1, f_2, f_3\} = \left\{\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}, \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right\}.$$

Comment: Why is the projection of $f(x) = x$ over the trigonometric polynomial the desired function, and not the other way around? Are they equivalent?

Comment: @Rodrigo see my reply under the other answer -- they are **very** different

Comment: @Rodrigo You want to find the trigonometric polynomial closest to the function $f(x) = x$, not a multiple of $f(x) = x$ closest to $a + b\sin x + c \cos x$.

Comment: @Rodrigo This other thing is given by $$\sqrt{\frac{3\pi^3}8}\left\langle x, a + b\sin x + c \cos x\right\rangle$$